# send image url and video url from android app to php server together

Tags: php, android

In my android app UI, user can select a video from gallery, after that i am fetching the selected video uri and creating a thumbnail of the video and storing it in users sdcard and getting the uri of the image.

Now i am using the below code to send the video to the server --

```
//Store video to server
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL+"?emailid="+uEmailID);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0){
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textViewResponse.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

The video is successfully uploaded to server, its working.
Now i want to send both the video and image url together, is that possible using my above code, any hint or idea is welcome.

Comment: Just write the form-data to the output stream like you did the uploaded file.

Comment: @frz3993.........any sample will be helpful

Comment: what server expects ?

Comment: @Akhil.......server code is in php, which is getting the upload url of video and store it in my server folder, i want to send both the urls of image and video. there i m confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
FileInputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
//Part below should go after the previous file boundary
 dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_image\";filename=\""+ imageFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
//Change this to whatever the content type is
 dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/png"+lineEnd);

 dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

 bytesAvailable = imageStream.available();
 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

 bytesRead = imageStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

 while (bytesRead > 0){
      dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
      bytesAvailable = imageStream.available();
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
      bytesRead = imageStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
}

dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

In php the file should be available in the `$_FILES['uploaded_image']` superglobal.

The multipart/form-data raw request body will look like this:

```
-----------------------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file"; filename="video.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4

[the bytes]
-----------------------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_image"; filename="filename.png"
Content-Type: image/png

[the bytes]
-----------------------boundary--
```

Both can have `name="uploaded_file"` and in PHP your `$_FILES['uploaded_file']` will contain details of both files similar to uploading multiple files.
Forgot to add, only the last boundary should have the two extra hyphens suffixed.

Comment: done with this method, but in server side $_FILES['uploaded_image'] is shown as empty

Comment: Nothing in the logcat?

Comment: Logcat value -- D/thumbPath :: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1514221279211.jpg
12-25 22:31:24.491 9088-9248/com.pkg.myapp I/VideoActivity: Server Response is: OK: 200

Comment: Have you remove the twohypens from the previous boundary? because only the last boundary should have it.

Comment: with little struggle i finally managed the success, thnx to u for the idea bro

Answer (score 0):

add the into an object model and parse it to json using Gson object then send the POST request as a json:

```
Data data = new Data();
data.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
data.setVideoUrl(videoUrl);
String jsonObject = new Gson().toJson(data);
// send the jsonObject to server here
```